# Why won't my nltk classification model persist with joblib?

Tags: python-2.7, persistence, nltk, joblib

I've noticed that others have had problems with this on different operating systems and I've also heard that there may be something within a module that disallows loading a persistent classification model.  I'm using a mac with python 2.7 and Enthought Canopy's editor.

This is what I'm using to export and it appears to work:

```
joblib.dump(classifier, 'nbv1.pkl')
```

And this is what I'm using to import via the shell:

```
joblib.load('nbv1.pkl')
```

This is the error I get:

AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute '_N'

I'm assuming this means that my model is not exporting properly.  I have also not been able to automate the export process within the program itself and must always do so with the shell.

Thank you very much for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to a compatibility issue with nltk classifiers.